# Is there any way to pass an ID from URL to views.py using generic views?

Tags: python, django

I need to pass id from the url slug. I am using generic views. This is my code for urls.py:

```
path('category/<int:pk>/details/',
         CategoryDetailView.as_view(),
         name='category-details'),
```

and I need to pass the `<int:pk>` value into views.py, so I can filter my queryset with this id.

 My views.py code:

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=Expense.objects.get_queryset(), **kwargs):
        queryset = object_list
        return super().get_context_data(
            summary_per_year_month = summary_per_year_month(queryset.filter(category_id= <int:pk> ))
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access values from the URL in `self.kwargs`.

```
queryset.filter(category_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Note that your `get_context_data` is the other way round than normal. Typically, you call `super()` and then add to the context dict. It looks like your way will work, but it will seem odd to other Django users. You could try writing it as follows:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    queryset=Expense.objects.get_queryset()
    context['summary_per_year_month'] = summary_per_year_month(queryset.filter(category_id=self.kwargs['pk']))
    return context
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the path parameters are stored in `self.kwargs`, a dictionary that maps the name of the parameter to the value. So you can make use of:

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        summary=summary_per_year_month(
            Expense.objects.filter(category_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        )
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs, summary_per_year_month=summary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `self.kwargs.get('pk')`.

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=Expense.objects.get_queryset(), **kwargs):
        queryset = object_list
        return super().get_context_data(
            summary_per_year_month = summary_per_year_month(queryset.filter(category_id=self.kwargs.get('pk')))
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that really helped me learn Django was to add breakpoints (pdb) in my code, then run dir() on each object I came across.

For example, `dir(self)` will tell you what properties and methods 'self' has (ie, kwargs, model, request, etc). Then you can start experimenting around with these properties: self.kwargs, self.request, self.model, etc, see what they return.

Soon enough, you would find out that self.kwargs returns a dictionary of arguments that includes 'pk', which you can access using get(). That's how you can access 'pk'.

To me, this simple trick unlocked most of my understanding of Django and python.